# What does this(null) mean in Java?

Tags: java

I see the following code in a source file. It is a constructor but I do not understand what the code `this(null)` means here.

```
public DefaultFurnitureCatalog() {
    this((File)null);
}
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It calls another constructor on the same object that has a single `File` parameter

Comment: Often if someone has cast the `null` to a type, such as `File`, it is because there are multiple constructors that take a single non-primitive argument and so disambiguation is required.

Answer (score 0):

It means calling an overloaded constructor which takes an `Object` of some sort but you do not pass an object, but a plain `null`.

Answer (score 0):

It calls the constructor `public DefaultFurnitureCatalog(File f)`  with a null parameter.
Why ? so `public DefaultFurnitureCatalog()`  will use the same logic than `public DefaultFurnitureCatalog(File f)` .

Answer (score 0):

Condition 1:

From Oracle Java Tutorial:

From within a constructor, you can also use the this keyword to call another constructor in the same class. Doing so is called an **explicit constructor invocation**.

If present, the invocation of another constructor **must be the first line in the constructor**.

So you can't create a File reference pointing to null before explicit constructor invocation.

e.g.: below code throws compilation error: call to this must be first statement in constructor

public class Hello {

```
public Hello() {
    File file = null;
    this(file);
    System.out.println("hello - 1");
}
public Hello(File file) {
    System.out.println("hello - 2");
}

public Hello(String str) {
    System.out.println("hello - 3");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Hello h = new Hello();
}
```

}

Condition 2:

Check your code, do you have more than one constructor which accepts one input parameter of type Object (in general)?

e.g., below code throws compilation error: reference to Hello is ambiguous, both constructor Hello(File) in Hello and constructor Hello(String) in Hello match

public class Hello {

```
public Hello() {
    this(null);
    System.out.println("hello - 1");
}
public Hello(File file) {
    System.out.println("hello - 2");
}

public Hello(String str) {
    System.out.println("hello - 3");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Hello h = new Hello();
}
```

}

To avoid ambiguity, typecast the null as below:

public class Hello {

```
public Hello() {
    this((File)null);
    System.out.println("hello - 1");
}
public Hello(File file) {
    System.out.println("hello - 2");
}

public Hello(String str) {
    System.out.println("hello - 3");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Hello h = new Hello();
}
```

}

Hope,this helps